# Passing attributes to chef via command line

Tags: string, ssh, chef-infra, chef-recipe, string-interpolation

This is driving me nuts, any help is massively appreciated.

Currently using a recipe to run an ssh command whereby the command takes in args and then uses that.

The escaping of the string string quotes is quite literally sending me insane; please help me SO, you're my only help. :D

This is the literal string that I need for my ssh:

```
ssh -i /home/ec2-user/.ssh/Test-Key.pem -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no  ec2-user@ipAddress echo '{\"attr\":\"value\"}' | sudo chef-client -o solr-restart -j /dev/stdin
```

it's wrapped in a command within the recipe like so:

```
command "ssh -i /home/ec2-user/.ssh/Test-Key.pem -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no  ec2-user@ipAddress echo '{\"attr\":\"value\"}' | sudo chef-client -o solr-restart -j /dev/stdin"
```

no matter how I try and manipulate the string I cannot get the output to be correct, it either removes the escaped characters in the json, or adds in additional ones.

I've tried to `echo '#{madness}'`

where madness = `madness = '{\"portAttribute\":\"'+"#{portNumber}"+'\"}'`

but still no luck, thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IMHO your string interpolation looks fine but as you want to run the following command on remote machine:

```
echo '{\"portAttribute\":\"#{portNumber}\"}' | sudo chef-client -o solr-restart -j /dev/stdin
```

Command should tweaked a bit more and be passed in recipe as:

```
command "ssh -i /home/ec2-user/.ssh/Test-Key.pem -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no  ec2-user@ipAddress 'echo \'{\\\"portAttribute\\\":\\\"#{portNumber}\\\"}\' | sudo chef-client -o solr-restart -j /dev/stdin' "
```

Answer (score 1):

This works
`{\\\"attr\\\":\\\"value\\\"}'`

Answer (score 1):

You reeeeeeally probably don't mean to be using `-j`, that totally overwrites whatever data is on the node already and is only intended for inital bootstrapping. After that, you don't pass data in on the command line, it comes from Chef Server.

Comment: isn't -j read in from son via the sdin? To better explain, the value that I'm passing in comes form a collection, that collection is a filtered subset of data taken from chef server, I don't believe I can do the stay other way, at least not that I've come across.  
I have many nodes, I need to filter the set and then iterate through that set connecting to each ip address in turn, but the kicker is that each ip has service on a particular port, which is what I'm passing in as well.
I'm using one recipe to run another but that in itself is causing issues with invoking another as lock file...

Comment: No the -j option takes a path a file. This is generally only used on the first run when using the older style self-registration bootstrap (which is usually only needed when dealing with auto scaling systems these days).

Comment: oh I see.  Might you have an alternative solution for what I'm trying to achieve?  ONe that is more elegant and less destructive?

Comment: Really the only main way to pass in that kind of truly run time data is via environment variables, but it's not pretty. Chef is really built for system level convergence. You could also keep that data in a data bag.

Comment: gotcha, I was touying with the idea of using a data bag and then deleting once the run has finished, that'd negate the need for them to passed in.  Although my next brick wall involes machine_execute - new SO question inbound - this may become a theme for these next weeks.